# Elastic query to return only max score records

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I will be passing one should query to elastic. It should fetch only max score record from the results.

```
Records in my index : 
    GET testindex1/_search
    "hits" : [
              {
                "_index" : "testindex1",
                "_type" : "doc",
                "_id" : "2",
                "_score" : 1.0,
                "_source" : {
              "name" : "xyz",
              "description" : "better",
              "place" : "kerala"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "testindex1",
            "_type" : "doc",
            "_id" : "3",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
              "name" : "abc",
              "description" : "best",
              "place" : "andra"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "testindex1",
            "_type" : "doc",
            "_id" : "1",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
              "name" : "mno",
              "description" : "good",
              "place" : "tamil"
            }
          }
        ]

    Query passed:



GET testindex1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "name",
            "query": "xyz",
            "default_operator": "AND"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "description",
            "query": "*",
            "default_operator": "AND"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "place",
            "query": "*",
            "default_operator": "AND"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


Results for the above query:

"hits" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "max_score" : 2.287682,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "testindex1",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 2.287682,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "xyz",
          "description" : "better",
          "place" : "kerala"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex1",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 2.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "abc",
          "description" : "best",
          "place" : "andra"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex1",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 2.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "mno",
          "description" : "good",
          "place" : "tamil"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

For the above query the max score is 2.287682, and i want to display only the record with max score. Records might be more than 1 in my scenario. I cant use must query. I want to fetch the best result from the query passed

Comment: "size" : 1 in your querry will return only 1 document

Comment: `hits` is already sorted by score. Use `"size": 1` like ^ suggested and your single result will be the one with the highest score.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. But i want all the max score results. If my result is having 5 max score records i want all the five, not just 1

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe elasticsearch provides something like this with one request.
There are two alternatives that come in mind.

1. If you have a maximum number of results, you can specify that number (e.g. I want the best 20 of all, even if there are more). Then ask for that `size: 20`, and then just filter the results on the application level. The `max_score` is available, also the score of every document is available as well.
2. The second one is to make a request with `size: 1` and `filter_path=hits.max_score` in order to get the max score and then make a second request adding the field `min_score` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-min-score.html . This means that for every request you need to make two actually, but you get the desired behaviour.